# Cannot do a POST request from React app to Wordpress Rest Api (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest, axios

I'm running a ReactApp (with Create-React-App) on localhost. I am trying to create a post on a Wordpress website with Rest Api. I'm using Axios. The wordpress site is hosted on a live server.

Chrome gives me the following network error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaAbS.png

Firefox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/giCuq.png

I checked the server logs. And there is no record of the app accessing the API. It also almost immediately gives me errors.

The strange thing is: whenever I do this from Postman or from a basic NodeJS file (with the same code) it just works and I receive a 201 response:

Postman:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEitV.png

I have setup CORS headers on the Rest Api server.

What can I try to fix this?

The Axios code:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    'headers': {
      "Authorization": 'Bearer HIDDEN'
    },
    url: 'HIDDEN/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
    data: {
      title: "Test"
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WordPress rest API you have to pass nonce, because WordPress now use nonce, for doing adding, deleting somethings so you should care of nonce.